# Is there a way to add specific number of columns in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to add all values from columns without knowing how many columns are in worksheet.

I'm using openpyxl and this code:

```
def CellVal(r, c):
    return sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'output.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
for m in range(2, 6):
    sheet.cell(row=m, column=1).value = CellVal(m, 2) + CellVal(m, 3) + CellVal(m, 4) 
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

It works only fine if I add more columns here:

```
sheet.cell(row=m, column=1).value = CellVal(m, 2) + CellVal(m, 3) + CellVal(m, 4) + CellVal(m, 5) + CellVal(m, 6) ...
```

But what if I have 100 columns ? "...+ CellVal(m, 100)".

How should the code look like without adding all columns manually in this single line?

Comment: Use `ws.iter_columns` (docs [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_cols))

Comment: Your function `CellVal` is **completely** redundant. You probaly want to use `sum(ws.iter_rows(min_row=m, max_row=m, min_col=2, values_only=True)`